# Windows ThreadPool API - wait until all tasks finished

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, threadpool

I'm trying to use [Windows Thread Pool API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as pat of my C program. In my scenario, I want to send many tasks to the thread pool, and wait until all tasks are finished, and there are no more pending tasks. After all tasks finished I want to close the thread pool and continue execution of my program.

I believe the way to achieve it is using the wait objects described in the link above, but I can't really figure out what is the right way to do that. Does anyone understand if it's possible and what is the right way to do that?

Comment: system can not know about your tasks and when it finished. you need do this yourself

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I do it myself? I'm running a series of tasks, and want to close my program when all the tasks are done.

Comment: you need yourself count tasks. say have `LONG dwTaskCount = 1`, every time when you add new task - call `InterlockedIncrement(&dwTaskCount)`, every time when you finish task - `void OnTaskDone() { if (!InterlockedDecrement(&dwTaskCount)) SomeSignal();` also once call `OnTaskDone()` after you finish add new tasks. in `OnSignal` you can set some event, or do another job.. however without more knowledge about your requirements - hard select the best implementation